# error using 'quad' function in matlab - integrating power to get energy

Tags: matlab, integral

I am  calculating capacitor voltage and current. Now I want to determine the energy also.  Energy is just the integral of power, however I cannot integrate my power function:

```
I_C=exp(-alpha*t).*(x5(1)*cos(omega_d*t)+x5(2)*sin(omega_d*t));
V_C=exp(-alpha*t).*(x6(1)*cos(omega_d*t)+x6(2)*sin(omega_d*t))+V_In; 
Pow_C=V_C.*I_C;
Pow_C_Function=@(t)Pow_C;
Energy_C=quad(Pow_C,0,tf)
```

I get the error: The integrand function must return an output vector of the
same length as the input vector.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

you should define I_C, V_C and Pow_C as functions (as you have done for Pow_C_Function). Currently they are just variables.

Comment: Like this?
     
     I_C_Function = @(t) I_C;
     V_C_Function = @(t) V_C;

And then use those like

    Pow_C_Function = @(t) V_C_Function*I_C_Function

Doesn't seem to work... could you give me an example of what you mean please?

Comment: I get this error now: Undefined function 'times' for input arguments of
type 'function_handle'.

For the line: Energy_C=quad(Pow_C,0,tf)

Answer (score 1):

Well, you've defined `I_C` and `V_C` as being two *matrices*, not two *functions*. The fix is simple:

```
I_C   = @(t) exp(-alpha*t).*(x5(1)*cos(omega_d*t)+x5(2)*sin(omega_d*t));
V_C   = @(t) exp(-alpha*t).*(x6(1)*cos(omega_d*t)+x6(2)*sin(omega_d*t))+V_In; 
Energy_C = quad(@(t)V_C(t).*I_C(t), 0,tf);
```

Also, have a look at `quadgk` or `quadl`, or if you're on Matlab R2012a or newer, `integral`.